# Haskell typeclass and duplicate behaviour

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm new to Haskell & trying to generalise some behaviour in a program so as to reduce the amount of code and have a simpler solution overall.

Say I have this type which represents a post code e.g. 'ABC 123':

```
type PostCode = ((Char, Char, Char), (Int, Int, Int))
```

and the behaviour of a `PostCode` should be cylic; i.e. `AAA 000` comes before `AAA 001`; 'A' to 'Z' for `Char` should rap-round, as should 0-9 for `Int`.

I've therefore extraced this type class:

```
class Cyclic a where
    next :: a -> a
```

which is simple enough.

So I then have an `instance` for each:

```
-- import Data.Char
instance Cyclic Char where
    next c = chr n
      where nxt = (ord c) + 1
            min  = 65
            max  = 90
            n    = if (nxt > max) then min else nxt

instance Cyclic Int where
    next i = n
      where nxt = i + 1
            min  = 0
            max  = 9
            n    = if (nxt > max) then min else nxt
```

which leaves me with several obvious points:

- the concept of `min` and `max` is duplicated
- next is reimplemented for `Int` when the only real difference is the values of its min and max, as well as the type

How can I abstract this behaviour correctly? Is there a way to have the cyclic behaviour for both `Int` and `Char` without having two differing implementations? What other Haskell features might I use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a default implementation for `next` in the type-class as in:

```
import Data.Char (chr)

class (Ord a, Enum a) => Cyclic a where
    min', max' :: a
    next :: a -> a
    next a = if max' < a' then min' else  a'
        where a' = succ a

instance Cyclic Char where
    min' = chr 65
    max' = chr 90

instance Cyclic Int where
    min' = 0
    max' = 9
```

---

Alternatively you can use a helper function which implements `next` within a closure as in:

```
class Cyclic a where
    next :: a -> a

-- a helper function to implement next within a closure
cycl :: (Ord a, Enum a) => a -> a -> (a -> a)
cycl min' max' a = if max' < a' then min' else a'
    where a' = succ a

instance Cyclic Char where
    next = cycl (chr 65) (chr 90)

instance Cyclic Int where
    next = cycl 0 9
```

Comment: Spot on. I thought I could do this but wasn't sure how I'd achieve it with my limited knowledge. Thanks!